# Display the char* value in VS textbox C++

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

I apologise beforehand if this has been asked many times but the problem is I cannot find the exact match to my question on here or Google in general.

I am trying to use VS C++ 2010 (windows form project) and cannot find a reasonable way to display a simple string (using char *variablename) in a textbox.

I pretty much worked out how to get anything else into the textbox:

```
String^ word1 = "hello";
int num1 = 23;
double num2 = 24.6;
float num3 = 25.9;

    //The above 4 work but the next 2 do not 
char *word2 = "hello";
string word3 = "hello"; //I have included <string>!

textBox1->Text = Convert::ToString(variablename);
```

If I use char* it outputs "true" and if I use string it just does not seem to be able to convert it.

The reason why I want to use either char* or string is because you cannot use String^ in a class! If I could use String^ in a class then I would but it is managed code.

Could anyone inform me as to how I get around this problem?

Comment: This is not C++.  I think it's C++-CLI, so I've retagged this question.

Comment: textBox1->Text = gcnew String("any char*");

Comment: Oh thank you makc! That is all it was. I cannot understand why I could not find that anywhere. Sorry about that John D I just thought that it would naturally fall under the category of C++. Solved in under 15 minutes.